# Jira - create rest api query

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api, jira-rest-java-api

I'm using the Jira API with the following call: https://site.url/rest/api/2/search?jql=project=PROJECT&orderBy=Resolveddesc, however, it's not showing as per applied order by resolved desc.
No static URL like - https://site.url/rest/api/2/search?%20Requests%22%20%20ORDER%20BY%20RESOLVED%20DESC

Also, I am looking to filter the following fields in RestAPI to improve the performance.

fields": ["summary","assignee","status"]

any help on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without sample data, it is hard to know if you data support those filtering.

Below should be what you want.

```html
https://site.url/rest/api/2/search?jql=project=PROJECT+order+by+resolved+desc&fields=summary,assignee,status
```

Comment: Thanks Mic. above worked. however, am not able to filter the comments section like who has worked on the ticket.

Comment: not quite sure what you mean. can you create a dummy project and add some issues to provide sample for testing

Comment: adding `comment` to fields should work if you only want to see the comment. don't know what you want to filter, it is not in the question

Comment: Hi Mic - thanks able to get the comment, similarly i need to get the history as well, below is the query but history is not displaying - rest/api/2/search?jql=project=ABC+order+by+resolved+desc&fields=key,summary,status,resolved,created,updated,comment,history

Comment: can you try to append `&expand=changelog` to your url to see if you can see `histories` fields